# Is there a way to validate a part of a form on the click of a button without actually submitting the form first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

So basically I have a form that uses some Angular, it is a register form and has quite a lot of fields so for a better user experience we decided to use angular to create a 'next' button half way through the form which takes the user to the second half of the form without refreshing the page. However, using basic validation like required is complicated because if the user misses something on the first page and then clicks the submit button on the second page, the 'this field is required' message will flash up but the user cannot see it because it appearing on the first screen.

Is there a way to validate each half of the form separately using something like angularJS or jquery validation plugin? I.e. can I validate the first half of the form when I click the 'next' button so the user cannot get onto the second half of the form without first filling in the first half.

Just a quick note: I tried using the Jquery Validation plugin but as I am also using angular so when I click the next button it does validate once, but then still allows me to move on to the next page.

Hope this question makes sense, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in angular way completely as you are using angular in your form. You can also add a check inside your submit function whether any field is invalid before sending the post request too.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>Validation Example</h2>

<form  ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="validateCtrl"
name="myForm" novalidate>

<div ng-show="!next">

<p>Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>Email:<br>
  <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
  </span>
</p>
<input type="button" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$invalid || myForm.email.$invalid" ng-click="movenext()" value="Next" />
</div>

<div ng-show="next">
  <input type="button" ng-click="prev()" value="Previous" /><br>
<p>Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && myForm.password.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="submit"
  ng-disabled="myForm.password.$invalid">
</p>
</div>
</form>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.next = false;
    
    $scope.movenext = function(){
      $scope.next = true;
    }
    $scope.prev = function(){
      $scope.next = false;
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm adapting/implementing this as we speak, so far so good! Thanks a lot & I'll let you know if I run into any problems

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
$("#form").validate();
```

you can also chose which elements to try and validate using:

```
$("#form").validate().element("#id");
```

this will manually fire the validation process without submitting the results, and it will also let you chose what elements you want to validate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This does kind of work, it does validate the field correctly, however my next button now does not work at all. At the moment I have this:     <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="tab = 2" id="nextBtn1">Next</a>

Comment: And the JS:
$(function() {
 $("#nextBtn1").on('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  $("#registerIndividualForm").validate().element('#firstName');
 });
});

Comment: can you provide a link so I can test it myself?

Comment: We are using xampp and local host as we are not on a server yet so I can't provide a link unfortunately

Comment: maybe you can reproduce only the relevant part into a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I've never used this tool so I can give it a go! We're using laravel so I have a layout file that has the head and body of the html and then the actual content of the form is in a different file, how would I set this up on jsfiddle?

Comment: I dunno much about laravel, but I assume that once the page is loaded in your browser you have the generated html code. go to source code and get it from there. if you are using chrome -> Ctrl + U

Comment: It's giving me a few different errors when I try this, looks like it's because of the PHP and stuff

Comment: ok so can you try to explain what is wrong now? what error are you getting when you run the valid() function

Comment: Well because I'm using angular to navigate between tabs in the same page, the code for switching is on the 'next' button which also is the button I have to click to validate the form using jquery, so when I validate it works but it still switches tabs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `keyup` [function](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/). Something like this:

```
$("input[type='email']").keyup(function(evt){
     validate($(this).val());
});
```

Where `validate` is a function where you check the input's value.

Anyway, if you want use the `keyup` function you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/piterio/7m49o87w/1/).

Comment: I've tried this: 
$(function() {
 $("input[type='email']").keyup(function(evt) {
  $('#registerIndividualSeller').validate({
   rules: {
    email: {
     required:true,
     email: true
    }
   }
  });
 });
});
To no avail, is this kind of what you meant?

Comment: I'm new to SO, how does one insert code properly into a comment/question?

Comment: When you start writing a comment you can see this text: "Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** ``code``. "

Comment: If you can reproduce your code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) we'll have more options to give you a correct answer